# Slow Batched Deletes On Azure SQL DB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have an application which needs to delete all of the data in all of the tables in a database. One of the tables contains around 150k records. I cannot truncate this table as it has FK constraints with some of the others.

When running on my machine against a local database, this takes only seconds to run. In this time, all data from all tables is deleted, including the 150k table. The local database is set to Full recovery mode.

When I point my application to a remote Azure SQL DB, the performance is terrible and most of the time fails with a time out.

I have tried upping the DTUs available to the Azure DB but this seems to have no effect.

My code:

```
using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(_myConnectionSting))
{
    destinationConnection.Open();

    foreach (string tableName in importExportTasks.Select(x => x.DestinationTableName))
    {
        string sql = @"
            DECLARE @BatchSize INT
            SET @BatchSize = 5000

            WHILE @BatchSize <> 0
            BEGIN
                DELETE TOP (@BatchSize)
                FROM {0};
                SET @BatchSize = @@rowcount;
            END ";

        string sqlCommand = string.Format(sql, tableName);

        using (SqlCommand cmd = destinationConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sqlCommand;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 240;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    success = true;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of this code against Azure DB? Something I am missing?

Comment: If you have to do it constantly - create stored procedure, and just pass table name as parameter. Also you you want delete all records, it is not necessary to do that in batches - "delete from {0} where 1 = 1" would work as well.

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis I disagree, using batches can minimize disruption due to log file growth, blocking, etc., and in Azure especially, you want to minimize unnecessary I/O, even if it makes the delete itself take a bit longer. But [you have to do it right](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis the Stored Procedure approach is also extremely slow. I think the issue comes from it being an Azure database, rather than the approach.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I totally agree that properly implemented batch delete would be perfectly valid approach, but in this this scenario it would delete 5k on first loop run, then all remaining on 2nd loop.

Comment: @James i would check DTU usage percentage (or max percentage) when your query is running to see if it's azure issue  https://portal.azure.com -> SQL Databases -> Select DB - Compute utilization for 1 hour. Also regarding stored procedures - it is almost same amount of time as running query directly, just so you do not have to send full sql command constantly (more convenient to use).

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis That's why I said "you have to do it right" - I was merely addressing you brushing off batch deletes in general, not any specific (incorrect) implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SQL Database is metered on various metrics.  One major one (for this example) is the log commit rate which is governed by the size of your resource reservation.  You can read about the limits in the vcore model here: [SQL Azure vCore Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vcore-resource-limits-single-databases).  You should be able to look at the various DMVs around resource stats usage [sys.dm_db_resource_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-resource-stats-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current) and you can also examine the specific use of resources by each query using the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017) which you can see with DMVs but is easier to navigate using SQL Server Management Studio since it has a nice UI.

It is highly likely that you just need a larger resource reservation to get faster delete performance.  If using a larger reservation size does not work, then please post information from the sources I've mentioned here and I or others can try to help you further.

Comment: Would this also apply for bulk inserts (bcp and the .Net equivalent)?

Comment: bulk inserts are going to likely be limited by log commit rate first, yes.  If you are doing processing on the data before really committing it, then you can often get faster performance by first inserting into tempdb (which is not going over the network to commit log since it is local to each machine only).  Super-high-end approaches can use the in-memory OLTP tables as staging in ETL pipelines with the non-durable table option.